# Handling Large JSON bodies in Salesforce

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, salesforce

Is there was way to digest large JSON bodies like you would with say a spring-boot project  `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)`. Where you do not have to have a DTO in its entirety matching the JSON body? I recently hit some limits with this approach of 1:1(DTO:JSON) and I have not been successful in finding something that will allow me to ignore the massive JSON bodies(7MB and UP).
Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JSON.deserialize(jsonString, apexType)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm). Unlike `JSON.deserializeStrict()` this method just ignores unknown attributes instead of throwing an exception.
You could test it in developer console:

```
String jsonString = '{ "unknown1": "aaa", "unknown2": "bbb", "type": "xyz", "id": "12345" }';
Data data = (Data) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, Data.class); // No Exception
System.debug(data);
try {
    Data data = (Data) JSON.deserializeStrict(jsonString, Data.class);
} catch(JSONException e) {
    System.debug('Exception thrown'); // You'll see this.
}

class Data {
    public String type;
    public String id;
}
```

Anyway if you have to handle more than 7MB of data, you should use an async transaction: the heap size limit is 6MB for synchronous one. [Governor Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm)

Comment: No way of async transactions through a REST API or anything like that, would need to read from file. anything like this is best handled off the platform (6mb higher) else the limits will get you.